# Create directory in SUSE (Linux) from Java code

Tags: java, linux, suse

How Can I create directory in an specified path on SUSE (Linux)? I have done it in Ubuntu by giving location like this:

```
String filelocation="/home/"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"/IE_Service/FormsSetting/";
```

Comment: What's wrong with that on SUSE?

Comment: You do this the same way as you create a directory in Java on any other version of Linux, or MacOS, or Windows.  (But not Android, 'cos Android isn't real Java.)

Comment: this is what i am doing.. works on UBUNTU..
   File fil= new File("/home/"+System.getProperty("user.name"+"/IE_Service"));
fil.mkdirs(); 

apparently when i debug i found " fil.mkdirs(); " terminates the program in SUSE